# add object in nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I want to add a small object in a large object. I have one position element. I want to add the small object in that position. But if there is some object already in that position then place the small object at the same level.

```
var object = { 'mcq': { 'options1': { 'image': { 'contact': {}}}, 'options2': {}, 'options3': {}}};

var position = "mcq.options1.image";
var add_element = {"number": {}};

//   output should be like this :
var object = { 'mcq': { 'options1': { 'image': { 'contact': {}, 'number': {}}}, 'options2': {}, 'options3': {}}};
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER FOR QUESTION IN COMMENTS**

```js
// Recursive function to traverse the object and set key and value of the new object param passed
function setValue(obj,path,add_element){
    if (typeof(path)=='string'){
        path = path.split('.');
    }
    if (path.length > 1){
        setValue(obj[path.shift()], path, add_element);
    }else{
        obj[path[0]][Object.keys(add_element)[0]] = add_element[Object.keys(add_element)[0]];
    }
}

var object = { 'mcq': { 'options1': { 'image': { 'contact': {}}}, 'options2': {}, 'options3': {}}};
var position = "mcq.options1.image";
var add_element = {"number": {}};

setValue(object, position, add_element);

console.log(object);
```

**Previous Answer**

Just add the small object as a new param for the existing object. When added like below, if the object key already exists, the value will be overwritten, if it does not exist, then will added to the same level as a new key.

```
object.mcq.options1.image.number = {};
```

```js
var object = { 'mcq': { 'options1': { 'image': { 'contact': {}}}, 'options2': {}, 'options3': {}}};

console.log(object);

object.mcq.options1.image.number = {};

console.log(object);
```

Comment: no this will not work because position is dynamic and store in variable.

Comment: var object = { 'mcq': { 'options1': { 'image': { 'contact': {}}}, 'options2': {}, 'options3': {}}};

console.log(object);

var position = "mcq.options1.image";

object[position] = {};

console.log(object);

Comment: please look above comment and in this my position is dynamic and store in variable.

Comment: @manishsingh, check my updated answer to accommodate the dynamic assigning

Comment: @manishsingh, if the answer did help you, please mark the answer as accepted. Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
<script>
var object = { 'mcq': { 'options1': { 'image': { 'contact': {}}}, 'options2': {}, 'options3': {}}};

var position = "mcq.options1.image";
var add_element = {"number": {}};
console.log(object);
//output should be like this:
object.mcq.options1.image.new = add_element;
console.log(object);

</script>
```

Fiddle...http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBJ62BGIT3E9 see here

Comment: The OP needs the path to traverse to be dynamic